# How to get programmatically the maxBytesLocalHeap for a specific cache?

Tags: ehcache

I am configuring my caches from an *`ehcache.xml`* file, among other configurations I set there the `maxBytesLocalHeap` for all the caches.

I also have a web interface where I have to show all the available caches, their actual size and their maximum size.

I am able to get the global `maxBytesLocalHeap` but I can not find a way to get this for each cache. Is there any method to do this? (Or an workaround if is not possible to get it via Ehcache public APIs)

PS: My caches are using only on-heap memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Flowryn..you can get the each & every detail about each Cache using **StatisticsGateway** Class...Use
**cache.getStatistics().getLocalHeapSizeInBytes()**
I addition to above there are many Methods which u can use to show on your web interface...

Let me know if you need any clarification on it.

Comment: Thank you Robin, just a clarification, can you also mention your current version? I think is 2.10. At this moment we're using 2.6 in our project and I think we will need to migrate since this method is not available there.

Comment: Yes i have 2.9 version. but there is one another way you can use just check  this [CacheStatistics](http://www.ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/management/CacheStatistics.html)........This contains the other methods like getOffHeapStoreObjectCount() getMemoryStoreObjectCount() ... May be useful